# ActiveDirectory lastLogonTimeStamp Inactive

Tags: active-directory, ldap, windows-server-2003-r2, schema, attributes

In joining a new company, I have inherited it's history.

I find that the User and Computer Object property lastLogonTimeStamp is not available.  I have checked that the AD Schema version is 2003 R2, and that the domain attribute ms-DS-Logon-Time-Sync-Interval was "" (which should default to 14, to which I've now explicitly set.)

If relevant, the first DC is a SBS server.  (This is my first time dealing with SBS, and so far I'm tempted to set it aflame.)

Checking random users and computers, I see no LLTS.  How can I force this property into existence?

This is the Schema entry for CN=ms-DS-Logon-Time-Sync-Interval:

[image: ms-DS-Logon-Time-Sync-Interval Schema]

Comment: What is the domain functional level?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several possible causes.  The likely cause is that your domain functional level is not yet set to windows 2003.  Once that's been established check out this KB article: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/886705

Comment: It's been so long since its really mattered, its easy to forget about functional levels